# merge all pairs of objects within a folder based on (pairwaise) string pattern (R or Python)

Tags: python, regex, r

I have two types of tables containing time series. One type contains data referring to population and are stored in files with a particular pattern at the end. The other type contains data regarding resources. Furthermore, I have files for different farms (hundreds). Thus, the content of the folder is:

```
Farm01_population
Farm01_resources
Farm02_population
Farm02_resources
Farm03_population
Farm03_resources
Farm04_population
Farm04_resources
........
```

And so on.

I also must do computations within each file. So far, I´ve started the task by first performing the calculations separately for population and resources.

```
population_files <- list.files("path",pattern="population.txt$")
resources_files <- list.files("path",pattern="resources.txt$")

for(i in 1:length(population_files)){......}

for(j in 1:length(resources_files)){......}
```

How could I merge now every pair of tables referring to each farm?, thus obtaining:

```
Farm01_finaltable
Farm02_finaltable
Farm03_finaltable
Farm04_finaltable
......
```

And so on.

As the number of farms is very big, I cannot write an specific string as pattern at the beginning of each file name. What I need to state is that tables must be merged that share the same pattern at the beginning, whichever this pattern (farm) is.

I am using R but solutions with Python are also welcomed.

Comment: By table, do you mean csv, txt, files or R files (.rdata, .rds)?

Answer (score 0):

Just keep everything all in one file

```
library(dplyr)
library(rex)

file_regex = 
  rex(capture(digits),
      "_",
      capture(anything))

catalog = 
  data_frame(file = list.files("path") ) %>%
  extract(file, 
          c("ID", "type"), 
          file_regex, 
          remove = FALSE)

population =
  catalog %>%
  filter(type == "population")
  group_by(ID) %>%
  do(.$file %>% first %>% read.csv)

resources =
  catalog %>%
  filter(type == "resources")
  group_by(ID) %>%
  do(.$file %>% first %>% read.csv)

together = full_join(population, resources)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming files are csv format, consider the following base R and Python 3 (using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)) solutions. Both use regex patterning to find corresponding population and resources files and then merge to a final table using a linked Farm ID. Do note if you need to iterate past 99 files, be sure to adjust regex digit count `{#}` to `{3}` (for Python do not change the string format operator `{0}`).

**R**

```
path = "C:/Path/To/Files"
numberoffiles = 2

for (i in (1:numberoffiles)) {  
    if (i < 10) { i = paste0('0', i)  } else { i = as.character(i) }

    filespop <- list.files(path, pattern=sprintf("^[a-zA-Z]*[%s]{2}_population.csv$", i))
    dfpop <- read.csv(paste0(path, "/", filespop[[1]]))

    filesres <- list.files(path, pattern=sprintf("^[a-zA-Z]*[%s]{2}_resources.csv$", i))
    dfres <- read.csv(paste0(path, "/", filesres[[1]])) 

    farm <- gsub(sprintf("[%s]{2}_population.csv", i), "", filespop[[1]])
    mergedf <- merge(dfpop, dfres, by=c('FarmID'), all=TRUE)
    write.csv(mergedf, paste0(path, "/", farm, 
                              sprintf("%s_FinalTable_r.csv", i)), row.names=FALSE)
}
```

**Python**

```
import os
import re
import pandas as pd

# CURRENT DIRECTORY OF SCRIPT
cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))    
numberoffiles = 2

for item in os.listdir(cd):

    for i in range(1, numberoffiles+1):
        i = '0'+str(i) if i < 10 else str(i)   

        filepop = re.match("^[a-zA-Z]*[{0}]{{2}}_population.csv$".format(i), item, flags=0)
        fileres = re.match("^[a-zA-Z]*[{0}]{{2}}_resources.csv$".format(i), item, flags=0)

        if filepop:
           dfpop = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(cd, item))

        if fileres:    
           dfres = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(cd, item))

           farm = item.replace("{0}_resources.csv".format(i), "")                        
           mergedf = pd.merge(dfpop, dfres, on=['FarmID'])
           mergedf.to_csv(os.path.join(cd, "{0}{1}_FinalTable_py.csv"\
                          .format(farm, i)), index=False)
```